# hdfs namenode -format error while setting up the hadoop

Tags: hadoop

when I downloaded hadoop-3.3.0 and after setting up I entered the command(hdfs namenode -format). It is showing

**error: couldn't find or load main class AKASH**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL0tB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop doesn't run well on Windows. More specifically, you cannot have spaces in your username or the Hadoop installation path, thus why it is showing an error with part of your `USERNAME` variable (which doesn't need set to run the format command, anyway).

It's recommended you use a Linux-based WSL2 environment or VM instead.